# Shrinking window results text being thrown out of a div

Tags: html, css

When hovering over an image in a grid, text and button shows. Point is, when window is shrunk content sticks out of a div.

This is a part of my first project i'm doing on a bootcamp, so I want to keep pictures with a 33% width (instead of doing it more responsive and wrapping to 50% -> 100% with @media), mostly because of the practice reasons before i jump to real RWD section.

I know i'm doing something wrong but i can't seem to find out what exacly.
Is there any way to prevent text sticking out?

Here comes a HTML

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Board game</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css">
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:400,700%7CRaleway:400,700%26display=swap%26subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            </head>

            <body>
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="gallery">
                        <h2 class="section-title">Choose your pick</h2>

                            <div class="gallery-grid">
                                <img src="https://listverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/monopoly.jpg" alt="monopoly" class="gallery-image">
                                <div class="gallery-middle">
                                    <div class="gallery-text">
                                        Some random Text
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="gallery-grid">
                                <img src="https://listverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/monopoly.jpg" alt="monopoly" class="gallery-image">
                                <div class="gallery-middle">
                                    <div class="gallery-text">
                                        Some more and more random Text
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="gallery-grid">
                                <img src="https://listverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/monopoly.jpg" alt="monopoly" class="gallery-image">
                                <div class="gallery-middle">
                                    <div class="gallery-text">
                                        Text
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="gallery-grid">
                                <img src="https://7.allegroimg.com/s512/03b26e/2a31184a4aa2b59e685e90c9fca7/Gra-Terraformacja-Marsa-znaczniki-3D-gratis-Stan-opakowania-oryginalne" alt="monopoly" class="gallery-image">
                                <div class="gallery-middle">
                                    <div class="gallery-text">
                                        <p> Random text </p>
                                        <button class="gallery-btn">More Info</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="gallery-grid">
                                <img src="https://listverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/monopoly.jpg" alt="monopoly" class="gallery-image">
                                <div class="gallery-middle">
                                    <div class="gallery-text">
                                        Text
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="gallery-grid">
                                <img src="https://listverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/monopoly.jpg" alt="monopoly" class="gallery-image">
                                <div class="gallery-middle">
                                    <div class="gallery-text">
                                        Text
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </section>
                </div> 
        </body>
</html>`
```

and a SCSS

```
$color-main: #fa8231;
$color-light: #f1f2f6;

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery-grid {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.gallery-image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.gallery-middle {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery-text {
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.gallery-grid:hover .gallery-image {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.gallery-grid:hover .gallery-middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.row::before,
.row::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.gallery-btn {
    color: $color-light;
    background: $color-main;
    border-radius: 10%;
    border: none;
    vertical-align: baseline;

}

.gallery-btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Leaving a link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Evenclan/0qh7pawk/15/

Comment: This page is acting as expected, text don't have enough of space so he going out of the container, you can solve this by changing the UI, changing font-size make it responsive with vw for example. But most important is to understand, that we need always to check out UI in all resolutions that we expect this to work, and 
add all the required adjustments, it's part of the process , embrace it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try playing with `.gallery-text` like:

```
.gallery-text {
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Use these properties: overflow, flex, max-width etc. with different values. Read their purpose too. For learning and playing, browser inspection element tab is the best as you can undo anything by reloading and save changes by simply copying from there and pasting in your css file.

Comment: Thank you for your input and mostly for your tip regarding browser inspection tab.
While I couldn't really fix my issue on a really low resolution screen I gonna accept your anwser as it helped me a lot, both codewise and in understanding what was going on :)

Comment: Glad I could help :-) Good Luck ahead.